# Error during Spring Boot application startup: BeanCurrentlyInCreationException in securityConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am encountering an issue while trying to run my Spring Boot application. The error is a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException related to the 'securityConfig' bean. It mentions a circular reference, but I'm unable to identify the source of the problem. The application fails to start, and I need help resolving this issue.

1. I've defined a security configuration class named 'SecurityConfig'.
2. Upon running the Spring Boot application, I encounter the following error.
3. The error message mentions a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException and refers to the 'securityConfig' bean.
4. I suspect there might be a circular reference, but I'm having trouble identifying it.

```
package com.criticine.config;

import com.criticine.repository.UserRepository;
import com.criticine.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.criticine.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.criticine.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserRepository userRepository, CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService,
                          JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
                    request.requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
                    request.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll();
                    request.requestMatchers("/api/users/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/users/checkEmailAvailability").permitAll();
                    request.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
package com.criticine.security;

import com.criticine.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- I'm using Spring Boot version 3.2.0
- I've checked for circular references in my code but couldn't find any.
- I've tried rearranging the order of bean creation, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the passwordEncoder is instantiated when the configureGlobal method is executed, and SecurityConfig is also being instantiated at this time, a circular reference is caused. The simplest way is to use static to modify the passwordEncoder method like the following

```
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```